# I want to roll up the world!

Tags: katamari-forever

We have been playing Katamari Forever on the PS3 and (I thought) beat the game. But my problem/complaint is that all the levels stop me at some point. They have a time limit. Or a size limit. Or stop you if your roll over a bear.

I just want to keep rolling until I feel like stopping. By preference, I want a nice outdoor level so I can roll up the world.

Is there some level I missed that will let me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is Eternal Mode. Specifically in *Katamari Forever,* there is no set target that I can find for unlocking the mode for the levels but it should become available after you solve a level three to four times.

I did find one note that reported that most stages in the RoboKing's Universe contain eternal modes. But only a few of the levels in the King's Universe feature it.

Comment: Okay, on several levels it *says* I've unlocked Eternal Mode. But when I play the levels they still seem to be timed. Do I have to do something to activate Eternal Mode for a level?

Comment: I don't have the game on hand at the moment to look and can't find a screen shot online but there should option to select mode when picking the level. I'll see what I can find.